# Why does using console.log change the output value of a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, function, console.log

console.log changes function output value

I thought console.log doesn't change an output for function.
Can someone explain why does this heppen?

```
function S(e) {
    for (var t = '', n = e.charCodeAt(0), i = 1; i < e.length; ++i)
            console.log(i, n ); 
        t += String.fromCharCode(e.charCodeAt(i) ^ ((i + n) & 127));
 
    return t;
}

S(":h_OWO4a'16*4g.&8kn") // return 'M'
```

and without using console.log completly different result

```
function S(e) {
    for (var t = '', n = e.charCodeAt(0), i = 1; i < e.length; ++i)
        t += String.fromCharCode(e.charCodeAt(i) ^ ((i + n) & 127));
 
    return t;
}

S(":h_OWO4a'16*4g.&8kn") // return 'Script error for "'
```

Comment: Missing braces in your for loop.

Comment: In your case it is missing braces, but there are plenty of ways that that calling `console.log` could change output depending on what you pass to it. (ie. mistyped equality checking `console.log(i = 0);` or incrementing in the log `console.log(i++);` etc.)